# Pushbullet app and facebook integration

Tags: facebook

Dear android users is there a possibility to integrate facebook with pushbullet?

If yes I would be really grateful for answer which will show me how can I do it.

1. By integration I mean that Writing messages from pushbullet and
   sending messages to a person from Facebook.
2. All messages, notifications from facebook.com will be shown in     pushbullet.

Comment: By integration, what exactly are you looking for? Sharing Facebook notifications to other devices?

Comment: Not only notifications. I will edit my question

Comment: Answering your Q2. Set up "notification mirroring" in PushBullet. The notifications will then be shown on every other device with PushBullet installed and signed in to by the same account.

Comment: But there is only available in pro version :C

Comment: Says who? I have a free account with "notification mirroring". I've been using that for a looooong time.

Comment: https://www.pushbullet.com/pro Look at this link

Comment: it seems the "reply" buttons on "mirrored notifications" are now premium-only. But the mirroring service is still free.

Comment: So what do I have to have the messanger installed on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and answer by myself.

The best idea is to use Facebook Lite. In setting change the option to show notification and you got fully integrated messages from Facebook with Pushbullet. Of course you may use Facebook Messanger but it seems to be a little bit laggy.